# IT Consultant engagement in a project

Tags: team-management, project-team, product-management, development-process, change-management

I have been asked as an IT consultant to help an insurance company to upgrade their legacy Information management system to more reliable and user friendly one which has to last for the next 7 years. I work for a consultation firm that has been asked to evaluate the project, review financial costs and set a plan to the management team. 
As a consultant, what documentations do need to do for the project? and also what tasks do I need to start with ? I have done a briefed document reviewing the company's legacy system and how it works based on my first meeting with the people involved! 
I am new on this business and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Potentially a dup of [What are the required documents should I prepare In order to start my Project](http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/9394/430).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methodology aside, as a consultant you have a few things you need to address that you pointed out yourself (because you've been specifically asked for them).

> I work for a consultation firm that has been asked to evaluate the project, review financial costs and set a plan to the management team.

To break that down, you've been asked to:

1. Evaluate the Project

   I'm assuming this means Evaluate their Existing Solution, because there is no project as yet. This is typically done in documents such as a **Business Case** document and/or a **Problem Statement** document. The purpose of both of these is to establish exactly *what is wrong* to ensure you're all on the same page as to what needs to be solved.
2. Review Financial Costs

   To review something I'm assuming you already have some costs there? Either way, this is getting into the **High Level Project Plan** territory (or specifically a portion of it which is called a **High Level Cost Estimate**). After you've defined and agreed *what is wrong* you'll need to come up with *how you can solve what is wrong*. This is typically at a High Level and done to give a ball-park indication of just how big the problem is and how long/much it may cost to fix it. The key here is not to go into details, you want just enough detail for the client to objectively decide whether this is worthwhile or not. A High Level Project Plan and High Level Costing is **not** a quote, it is pre-quote, it's simply and indication of size and complexity of the problem and possible solutions.
3. Set a Plan to the Mgmt Team

   Here is where you'd complete your **High Level Project Plan**. It will define (again, at a high level) the problem statement, business case, possible high level solutions with a recommended solution, and for that recommended solution you'd have a Project Plan that would indicate a potential timeframe and phases that would give the client an indication on Who, What, When, Where, Why and How of the project.

Then you'd be at a stage where the Client can make an objective decision as to whether to proceed with your proposed solutions. They'll know (and will have all agreed to) **what is wrong**, they will have an indication of **how to solve it** and will also have an indication of **how much it will cost and how long it will take**.

This Project Planning Document can then form part of your contract/agreement with the Client going forward as it gives you both a common understanding of all elements of the problem, the solution and the path in between the two.

Comment: That's just an excellent answer for my question. Your answer highlighted issues that I had in mind of where to start.  Thank you for your time.